# Cannot install opencv with pip, because old Python

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install with pip python-opencv, but it requires numpy. So pip gets numpy, but it can't install it, because it needs Python >= 3.6 ! I have another PC with Python2.7 and OpenCV 4.2.0, so that shouldn't be a problem. How can I overcome this problem? I installed numpy before opencv, so it wouldnt try to get latest version, yet it still does.

Answer (score 1):

I just used --no-dependencies and specified 4.2.0.32. That worked

Answer (score 0):

The (slightly obvious) answer is to update Python! If it says it needs a python version greater than 3.6, update Python to version 3.6 or higher.

Comment: This might answer the question but more as comment rather than answer.